# iOS, How to alternate simple UIView instances of graphics with animateWithDuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm not sure how to proceed. I want to animate a slight graphics changes. I need this to happen in a loop every 2 seconds.

I have some drawing code in a class within a drawrect method. I pass in a style parameter with a custom method initWithFrame.

Within my animation animateWithDuration block, I thought I could just removeFromSuperview then addSubview different styled instances.

I know this sounds like the wrong approach.

However, I wasn't sure how else to do this.

Can anyone give me some options / point me at an example ?

Comment: Adding and removing from superview is not an animatable case. You can fade it in/out using alpha property. Once first view completed fading out, remove it from superview and add the second one and start to fade it in.

Comment: @krafter You cannot animate it with `animateWithDuration`, but with `transitionWithView` one can animate the adding or removing of a subview, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is call `drawRect:` once every 2 seconds, then create an `NSTimer` using the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:::::` method.  In the timer handler call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your original question about whether you should remove and re-add the view, typically you wouldn't do that (as that's a little inefficient). I usually have a public property in my custom view that (a) the view controller can set; and that (b) is used by the `drawRect` method. I then implement a custom setter that not only saves the ivar backing the property, but calls `setNeedsDisplay`, too (which will trigger `drawRect` to be called for you).

You haven't described what is changing in the view, but let me give you a random example. Let's say you have a `drawRect` that draws a circle of a given `radius`. Then my `UIView` subclass might have a property for this `CGFloat`, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat radius;
```

And then I might implement a custom setter which will not only update the ivar, like usual, but also triggers the re-calling of `drawRect`:

```
- (void) setRadius:(CGFloat)newRadius 
{
    _radius = newRadius;   //note, I set the ivar backing the property; do not try self.radius = ..., because that will call this same method with infinite recursion
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Then, when my view controller wants to update the view, it can simply do the following:

```
customView.radius = 27.5;
```

Or, if I want to animate the changing of this every two seconds, fading to the new position, every two seconds, I'd wrap the changing of this property in a `transitionWithView` block:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:customView
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    customView.radius = 27.5;
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Now, clearly this is a random example where this property was a `CGFloat`, but you can do this with any custom property that your `drawRect` needs to reflect the new rendering of the screen.